# OCR of digits. Classify with Hu Invariant Moments

Tags: java, algorithm, opencv, ocr, classification

I am doing OCR of pictures with several digits. I isolate the digits, calculate the **seven hu invariant moments** of each digits, and store the data. So when I have sufficient data for each digit, I want to match one incoming digit with the data I already have.

I start by calculating the seven hu moments for the digit, and I go through all the data and check if some other hu moment vector matches my newly arrived digit.

For the number **6**, the seven hu moments may look like this:

```
0.0015019597635929924
8.216737738246056E-7
2.0375639403591246E-10
7.83546684255912E-11
7.317864741055554E-21
3.429093590309372E-14
-6.668347984552349E-21
```

The other sixes are also quite similar.

The digit **1** may have data like this:

```
0.0013343457573374317
7.801615619419164E-7
1.2084360881640018E-10
2.0011222038541843E-10
3.0737764628109555E-20
1.7596117047839112E-13
4.854579634937481E-21
```

So if I receive hu moments for a 1, I want it match the best with the 1-data. How should I approach this, and what is the best method to implement it? I am using **Java** with **OpenCV** to calculate the moments.

**EDIT**: One additional question: Right now I have just isolated each digits with a bounding box around each digit, and calculated the hu moments of that image. Is it more accurate to calculate the hu moments of the contours around the digit itself instead? If so, anyone who care to explain the approach?
By simply doing:

```
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();    
   Imgproc.findContours(image, contours, new Mat(),Imgproc.RETR_LIST,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    Moments mom = new Moments();
    mom = Imgproc.moments(contours.get(0), false);
    Mat hu = new Mat();
    Imgproc.HuMoments(mom, hu);
```

I sometimes end up with just zero-values as hu moments. Is contours.get(0) the right argument to pass to moments-calculation?

**EDIT2:** Sorry for the edits, but from what I have tried on myself now, the hu invariant moments I calculate are too similar. I am not able to distinguish them in a smart way. Probably the way I calculate them now is too "rough". I am actually just finding the largest countour in every digit image, i.e. the bounding box image for each digit, and calculating the hu moments from that.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to use or construct a large database, this web site have many data: [machine learning data set collection](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html)

Second, the best thing is to use the boosting with neuronal network classifier or decision tree, in my case i use the C4.5 algorithm with this database [Pen-Based Recognition of Handwritten Digits Data Set](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Pen-Based+Recognition+of+Handwritten+Digits)  and it give me a rate of 99% that is pretty much. i thing all these algorithm are already implemented in the boost library.
for java try [weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/)